# Multiple webkit transitions in one line

Tags: html, css

```
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
     -moz-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
       -o-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
          transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s;
```

This effects the size of a div element when it is animated/moved, but I also have a requirement to adjust the opacity of it as well:

```
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
     transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
```

Do these go one after another in my style sheet or is there a way for me to combine them into one? Is there a best practice?

Comment: no..,  -webkit is for safari and chrome , -moz is for Mozilla, -ms is for ie and -o is for opera , after that u have to write normal style also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a comma to separate the properties in order to combine them (like you yourself did in the first example)

```
-webkit-transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s,opacity 0.4s ease-in;
transition: width 0.4s, height 0.4s,opacity 0.4s ease-in;
```

### [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/KVNNNJ)

---

Just for completeness: the following is the formal syntax of the transition property from [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-property-property):

> Value:    none | `<single-transition-property> [ ‘,’`
>   `<single-transition-property> ]*`

Which shows that multiple properties may be transitioned when separated by a comma.